# Chrome "onclick" event issue

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome

Okay so I am building an application (for Chrome (*not extension)) and have a bunch of repeated elements on the page. So I decided to build these elements dynamically using a loop, like so:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 64; i++){
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.id = "element"+i;  
    elem.onclick = "doSomething()"
    $("parentElement").appendChild(elem);
}
```

My issue occurs when it tries to attach my function to the onclick event. When I look at the element there is no onclick attribute on it... Even when I step through I can get to the line:

```
elem.onclick = "doSomething()"
```

Then I step again and nothing... So far I have tried with and without quotes and both .onclick and .onClick...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the function itself at all times, not a string of any kind.

```
elem.onclick = doSomething;
```

This will set `doSomething` as the click handler.

- Using strings will call `eval` internally, which is slow and possibly unsafe (the latter does not apply here).
- Passing a function directly is more straight-forward.
- Strings are only necessary if you set `onclick` through HTML.

Comment: Thank you! Now what if I want to pass in a parameter into doSomthing()? Should I just use an annoymous function? Such as elem.onclick = function(){doSomething(obj.id)}

Comment: @ThisGuy84: Yes, that's the way to go.

Comment: Still having an issue... When I appendChild it removes the onclick event!

Comment: Yes, this though is more what I am trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/uM4XN/1/ and that works too but when I simply run my app in chrome when I step through, the onclick is there but when I look at the element the onclick is gone...

Comment: Okay I got it to work... My for loop was off by one so I was not seeing the change on the element I was clicking... Thank you very much for your help! @pimvdb

Answer (score 1):

"addEventListener" is a better approach (in case you want to unbind later/bind more events). In addition, I would recommend caching a reference to the parent element, like so

```
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    elem;
for(var i = 1; i <= 64; i++){
    elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.id = "element"+i;  
    elem.addEventListener('click', doSomething);
    docFrag.appendChild(elem);
}
$("parentElement").appendChild(docFrag);
```

Depending on the size of the list, you may consider event delegation:

```
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    elem,
    parent = $("parentElement");
for(var i = 1; i <= 64; i++){
    elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.id = "element"+i;
    elem.className = "clickMe";
    docFrag.appendChild(elem);
}
parent.appendChild(docFrag);
parent.addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
    if( event.target.class === 'clickMe' ) {
        doSomething(event);
    }
});
```

(the class name "clickMe" is completely arbitrary)

Edit: both of these examples fell into the OP's trap of appending to the DOM within a loop. This should be avoided whenever possible, as touching the DOM is expensive. The examples have been updated to instead create a document fragment which is populated and then appended to the parent element. This makes caching a reference to the parent unnecessary in the first example.

Comment: I was looking into this route as well! I was hesitant though because I was not sure if I would be able to pass in the element. However it looks like you just answered that fear.